# Postgresql: Updating database schemas without having to reset data?

Tags: javascript, postgresql

Whenever I update database schemas, I am unable to access the data that was previously stored. The only way I have been able to get it back was by manually reset the database (db.sync({force: true})) and then re-entering the data using Postico, which is impractical for larger databases.

I was wondering if there was a way to add columns or otherwise modify a schema that would not require me to do this.

Comment: You mean ddl statements like alter table??

Comment: Define "update database schemas". What exactly are you doing?